# How do you make a call to a new Android Honeycomb sdk method without breaking backwards compatibility?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, android

I am not worried about screen real estate.  They have changed behavior and added new methods for tablet support.  If I call one of these I assume that would cause a run-time failure for the older SDKs.  Does this cause me to need a separate tablet version?  This is the first time I have had to deal with this on Android and it wasn't clear to me what to do.

Documentation was incorrect and it worked.  Don't know why I didn't think of reflection (doh!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those methods resides in some classes, which are not the part of pre-honeycomb SDK's you can try to use reflection to get (or not to in case of older devices) a honeycomb's class instance and call it's methods.

If you tell what methods/classes you are trying to use, i can try to make my answer more specific.